# How to make ion-select popover render correctly after input focus changes from keyboard to non-keyboard input?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, select, keyboard, ionic3

**(Ionic 3)**

In my `component HTML` i have a `select box (ion-select)` that displays some options.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="p" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>{{"somePage.bId"|translate}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="tel" formControlName="pId"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>{{"somePage.defect"|translate}}</ion-label>
      <ion-select formControlName="error" interface="popover">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.error">{{option.description}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>{{"message"|translate}}</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea
        rows="13"
        formControlName="message"
        autocorrect="on"
        autocomplete="on">
      </ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <button *ngIf="!..." ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="...">{{"submit"|translate}}</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

When the first thing a user `selects is the select box`, then it opens and is **scrollable** as one would expect.
[image]

But if one would `select number input first`, the `keyboard` opens. After entering the `number` and `tapping the select box`, it opens but can't be **scrolled** and is **overflowing** the screen.

[image]

Obviously, the `popover` is calculated bigger on the smaller screen, through to the **keyboard overlay** leading to a taller window height, which the following `log` shows `(*Height* being the select box height, and window height is self-explanatory)`.

[image]

**(The second line displays the buggy case)**

I am using the current `ionic-angular version 3.9.9.`

Are there any **workarounds/solutions** for this, so the `popover renders` correctly?